# Heavy water neutron slowing equation

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

How can I find some equations about neutron slowing effects of heavy water? how much heavy water is required to slow down a given percentage of neutrons to a required degree(For example how can I keep 150kg of U235 without blowing up in just one block with least amount of D2O)

Comment: Heavy water won't affect the neutrons inside the block of $\mathrm{^{235}U}$. And since 150kg is almost three times the critical mass of a sphere of pure $\mathrm{^{235}U}$, you *really* don't want it in the form of a single cubical block. You could make a thin slab of it, I guess.

Comment: Heavy water is a moderator to slow down neutrons velocities  but it acts also as a thermal neutrons reflector and so , it decreases the critical mass of 235 U .